# file_paths.xml can't read from string resources

Tags: java, android, android-resources

My purpose is to capture photo and save . But app throwing error if I use string builder on file_paths.xml to dynamically define file path.

I have 2 build types(test,release). I want to files_paths.xml dynamically read from string resources . For example I have 2 build types in build.gradle (module app):

```
    release {
            ...
            resValue "string", "appName", "Easyloan"
            resValue 'string', 'images_file_path', "Android/data/humo.tj.easyloan/files/Pictures"
        }
        // local test server
        debug {
             ...
            resValue "string", "appName", "Test-Easyloan"
            resValue 'string', 'images_file_path', "Android/data/humo.tj.easyloantest/files/Pictures"
        }
```

My file_paths.xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="el_images"
        path="@string/images_file_path" />
</paths>
```

Java code to get uri for file

```
            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".fileprovider", photoFile);
                pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(pictureIntent,
                        REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

AndroiManifest.xml :

```
...
 <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
...
```

But I am getting error when I am trying to take photo. Error message:

```
2019-06-21 19:55:56.248 8275-8275/humo.tj.easyloantest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: humo.tj.easyloantest, PID: 8275
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/humo.tj.easyloantest/files/Pictures/IMG_20190621_145556_1720187320.jpg
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
        at humo.tj.easyloan.fragmentsNewapplication.Fragment4.openCameraIntent(Fragment4.java:176)
        at humo.tj.easyloan.fragmentsNewapplication.Fragment4.lambda$null$0$Fragment4(Fragment4.java:100)
        at humo.tj.easyloan.fragmentsNewapplication.-$$Lambda$Fragment4$c1wFOH2hFscxkFmF0i4x39JUikc.onClick(lambda)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1136)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3121)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to files_paths.xml dynamically read from string resources

Sorry, that is not supported.

> My file_paths.xml looks like :

If you used `<external-files-path>`, you would not need the `Android/data/.../files/` portion of your `path` values, and those `path` values would be the same for both build types.

Comment: But my path's Android/data/.../files/ are not the same. For test build Android/data/humo.tj.easyloantest/files and for release: Android/data/humo.tj.easyloan/files

Comment: What will you recommend me?

Comment: @Yakub: `<external-files-path>` already takes your application ID into account, as it uses `getExternalFilesDir()`, which is (hopefully) what you are using to save the file in the first place. So, please use `<external-files-path>`. See [the `FileProvider` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#SpecifyFiles) for more details.

Comment: <external-files-path name="images" path="." />